# How to shuffle a char array - JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I am not sure how to shuffle a char array using Java so could anyone
help me, but please keep it really simple because I'm at GCSE level right now, Thank you.

Comment: Your question should show some evidence of previous research. Can you present what you tried / read by now?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method like:

```
Character[] myarray = ...
List<Character> charList = Arrays.asList(myarray);
Collections.shuffle(charList);
Character[] myShuffledArray = (Character[]) charList.toArray();
```